# How to use actual module instead of using mock

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have below Jest config

```
  jest: {
    configure: {
      testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
      preset: 'ts-jest',
      transform: {...},
      moduleNameMapper: {
        antd: '<rootDir>/__mocks__/antd/index.tsx'
      },
      testMatch: ['<rootDir>/src/**/*.test.(ts|tsx)$'],
    },
  },
```

In `<rootDir>/__mocks__/antd/index.tsx`

```
class Select extends Component<SelectProps> {

  static Option: FC = (props) => <option {...props} data-testid="mock-selectOption"  />;

  render() {
    const {
      ...props
    } = this.props;
    // @ts-ignore
    return <select {...props} data-testid="mock-select" />;
  }
}
```

I have a Select Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Select as MySelect } from 'antd';

const { Option } = MySelect;

export interface SelectOption {
  id: string;
  label: string;
}

interface SelectProp {
  options: SelectOption[];
  selectedOption: string;
  onChange: (key: string) => void;
}

function Select({ options, selectedOption, onChange }: SelectProp) {
  return (
    <MySelect value={selectedOption} onChange={onChange} >
      {options.map((opt) => (
        <Option key={opt.id} value={opt.id}>
          {opt.label}
        </Option>
      ))}
    </MySelect>
  );
}

export default Select;
```

I have a test case

```
import React from 'react';
import { fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import { render } from 'setupTests';

import Select from './Select';

jest.mock('antd', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('antd');
  return { ...originalModule };
});

describe('Select', () => {
  const handleChange = jest.fn();
  const mockProps = {
    options: [],
    onChange: handleChange,
  };
  it('render successfully', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Select {...mockProps} />);
    getByTestId('asca'); // use for debug
  });
});
```

`getByTestId('asca')` will make the test case fails, then I see below DOM modal

```
    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="asca"]

    <body>
      <div>
        <select
          data-testid="mock-select"
        />
      </div>
    </body>
```

which turns out still using the mock but not the actual `antd` component.

I've tried to add

```
     beforeEach(() => {
       jest.unmock('antd');
     });
```

but still got the same result.

How can I use the actual module instead of mock?

Comment: Why you import `Select` component from `./Select` rather than `antd`

Comment: @slideshowp2 This is my custom component. I've updated above. Please check

Answer (score 1):

Use [jest.unmock(moduleName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestunmockmodulename) API is correct,

> Indicates that the module system should never return a mocked version of the specified module from require() (e.g. that it should always return the real module).

But you need to know:

> When using `babel-jest`, calls to `unmock` will automatically be hoisted to the top of the code block.

If you import the `Select` component and call `jest.unmock()` in `beforeEach` hook. When running the test case, the mock `Select` component has been imported, then the `beforeEach` hook execute. it's too late for jest to unmock the `Select` component.

Now, you have two options:

`__mocks__/antd/index.tsx`:

```
import { SelectProps } from "antd/lib/select";
import React, { Component, FC } from "react";

class Select extends Component<SelectProps<any>> {
  static Option: FC = (props) => <option {...props} data-testid="mock-selectOption" />;

  render() {
    const { ...props } = this.props;
    // @ts-ignore
    return <select {...props} data-testid="mock-select" />;
  }
}
```

`Select.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Select as MySelect } from 'antd';

const { Option } = MySelect;

export interface SelectOption {
  id: string;
  label: string;
}

interface SelectProp {
  options: SelectOption[];
  selectedOption: string;
  onChange: (key: string) => void;
}

function Select({ options, selectedOption, onChange }: SelectProp) {
  return (
    <MySelect data-testid='asca' value={selectedOption} onChange={onChange}>
      {options.map((opt) => (
        <Option key={opt.id} value={opt.id}>
          {opt.label}
        </Option>
      ))}
    </MySelect>
  );
}

export default Select;
```

**1. Call `jest.unmock()` API in module scope of test file(Put it after the `import` statement is ok, it will be hoisted to the top of the code block)**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import Select from './Select';

jest.unmock('antd');

describe('Select', () => {
  it('render successfully', async () => {
    const handleChange = jest.fn();
    const mockProps = {
      options: [],
      onChange: handleChange,
      selectedOption: '',
    };
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Select {...mockProps} />);
    expect(getByTestId('asca')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

**2. Call `jest.unmock()` API in `beforeEach` hook or `it` functional scope, then dynamic import the `Select` component.(Dynamic import statement must put after the `jest.unmock()` API)**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';

describe('Select', () => {
  it('render successfully', async () => {
    jest.unmock('antd');
    const Select = (await import('./Select')).default
    const handleChange = jest.fn();
    const mockProps = {
      options: [],
      onChange: handleChange,
      selectedOption: '',
    };
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Select {...mockProps} />);
    expect(getByTestId('asca')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/73274190/Select.test.tsx (11.55 s)
  Select
    ✓ render successfully (1156 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.049 s, estimated 13 s
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['jest-extended'],
  setupFiles: ['./jest.setup.js'],
};
```

package version:

```json
"antd": "^4.16.12",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
```